# Is there a recommended path to upgrade from Qt Extended to a newer Qt framework?

Tags: qt, qtembedded

I'm looking at a Qt Extended application built circa 2006-2008 and upgrading to a newer Qt framework. What direction(s) are recommended to upgrade / rewrite this application to get on the latest supported version of some Qt framework?

Comment: What is a "Qt Extended application"?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Extended Basically Qt Extended was a (guess what;) an extension to the Qt framework at the Qt4 era, with further features targeting embedded systems. Some of that functionality were integrated into Qt5, some of it not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is an embedded platform, and in this is case first of all you need to get Linux BSP with newer Qt version (you can look into [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) or [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) or even a distribution like Debian, all of these have excellent support for Qt), and make sure that you have full HW supported for your platform. This is pretty much platform and product dependent, so i can't really be more specific.
After you got the OS up and running, you can start to port your application to port to Qt5. This can be pretty straightforward (see for example https://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5), but can be rather complicated if a lot of Qt Extended related features were used. Again, this depends a lot on the application itself, so hard to give guidelines.